# Parallel For hanging application

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm attempting to run some code to load pictures on demand to a structure in the background whilst the main UI thread picks loaded pictures and displays them in a winform.

It's not that quick so I've been trying to use Parallel.For to speed things up. This causes the entire application to become unresponsive. I've read other posts that say run this from its own (not the UI) thread but still its very slow (30 seconds plus) to update the form.

What point am I missing?

```
public ImageManager()
{    
    Thread LoaderThread = new Thread(Loader);
    LoaderThread.Start();
}

private void Loader()
{    
    ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,            
    };

    while (true)
    {  //start,end modified outside the class.
        Parallel.For(start, end), options, m =>
        {
            LoadAndRescale(m);
        });
    }        
}
```

Comment: `while (true)`? When this loop ends?

Comment: when the form closes. I've stripped out cancellation stuff for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Adding N threads will not make things faster if you don't have N CPU cores (and even then there's the hard disk as an even worse bottleneck). If it takes time then it takes time. You can only make it more convenient to the user by indicating that some work is in progress, and that they should wait a bit.

Also, maybe you don't have to show all N images right away. Maybe you can show only one, or a few, and in the background load the rest, to be shown when required.

One problem that you may have with Parallel.ForEach is that it uses all available threads, including the main one. The solution would be to provide your own `TaskScheduler` to it, instead of the `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: This is a consideration, but as I see it we're using 32 core systems so I'm happy to abuse that!

Comment: Added one more bit of info.